# Does UserInteractionEnabled work like Alpha for a UIView Hierarchy?

Tags: ios, uiview

I know that if I set the Alpha for a parent UIView to to 0 that all its children are also 'invisible'.  Is it also true that setting a parent UIView's UserInteractionEnabled to NO affect it's children in anyway?  In other words will making a superView untouchable make its subViews untouchable?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, but not in the same way. Basically, if you set a UIView.userInteractionEnable to NO, It will no longer process touch events, which means it will not be passing events to sub-views. You can, however, set userInteractionEnable to NO for sub-views with out impacting parent views or peer views.